# can a C++ function be defined using 'virtual inline'?

Tags: c++, inline, virtual

I see a C++  function being defined as below:

```
int virtual inline fun()
{
   return xxx;
}
```

I wonder what it means? 
anyone can explain it?

Comment: C/C++ doesn't exist first lesson.

Comment: Any function can be `inline`, but only non-static class member functions can be `virtual`.

Comment: C/C++ is undefined behaviour in C and C++, is the second lesson.

Comment: @Bathsheba what about overloaded operators?

Comment: @Quentin You are taking things to the absurd ;)

Comment: @Stargateur what do you mean?

Comment: @AndrewGong There is C and there is C++, you can't mix them like that was one language C/C++, for example, your question don't make any sense in C, cause C don't have virtual key word. So please tag only one language in your question. Let other people decide if the question need more that one tag.

Comment: @Stargateur yes, you are right. thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

It simply means the code doesn't compile.

Only non-static methods can be `virtual`. In your example `fun` is a free function so `virtual` cannot be applied to it.

Comment: but the function with this form does exit. and I can compile it in my vs2015 successfully.

Comment: @AndrewGong I highly doubt it. There is no way this can compile.

Comment: unless that is a method, but you haven't shown that in your post. In your post you showed a free function. That can't compile. If the code you are having and the code you are showing differ, that's another problem. And we can't start guessing what your real code is.